# URL Rewriting on Apache Linux

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Thanks in advance !! Actually i am suffring from url rewriting problem in php (apache server). Problem is :

I have to write
                    
**URL(Old)= abc.com/search_result.php?id=110**
 to

**URL(New)= abc.com/110**

it is working in opposite direction 
 when i click the url 
 **abc.com/search_result.php?id=110**
 it does not change to 
 **abc.com/110**

but 
 when i click the url  
 **abc.com/110**
 it changes to 
 **abc.com/search_result.php?id=110**

.htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://www.abc.com/search_result.php?id=$1
```

website linnk : [ncrfloors.com][1]

**Please anybody help me.....**

Comment: help.. help... help..help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On your old domain:** Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search_result\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://abc.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot bro.., Its works for me. I have been suffering from a long ago. Now it is solved through your help..

Comment: Hi @anubhava , what i need to do if i want to add more parameters in that url (other than id).

Comment: @amit: That will require 2 new rules 1 for external and 1 for internal redirect. I suggest opening a new question with a link to this question so that problem can be answered separately without changing a working answer.

Comment: Hi @anubhava , As per your suggestion i have opened a new question.If possible please help me.. Thanks

Comment: I posted answer on that question.